# GDI+ C++ Texture Brush Pattern from Bitmap

Tags: c++, gdi+, brush

I've been trying to do this for a couple of days now. Google had no answers anywhere.

The problem is that I need to pass an Image type as a parameter in TextureBrush. I only have an HBITMAP. I've looked at quite a few possibilities and no success.

Here is what I have:

```
// change my HBITMAP to GDI+ BITMAP
Bitmap bmpTestingIt(hbmBGTiles, NULL);

Graphics g(buffer.getBufferDC());
//Image image(L"C:/Users/Owner/Pictures/testbmp.bmp"); // This works but not what I need
//Image image(bmpTestingIt); // No
//Image image((Image)bmpTestingIt); // No
Rect rct(0, 0, bmpTestingIt.GetWidth(), bmpTestingIt.GetHeight());
TextureBrush brush(&image, rct);
g.FillRectangle(&brush, 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`Bitmap` inherits from `Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420.aspx) , I'm unclear why you need any of the commented lines. Instead just use `&bmpTestingIt` instead of `&image`. Just make sure you're [constructing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314.aspx) the `Bitmap` correctly (which should come down to passing the `HPALETTE` if it's not a device-independent bitmap; if it is a DIB, you're fine).